# How to reload javascript after partial render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, renderpartial

There are Products that has_many Images. On the Product edit template there is a partial for adding and deleting Images

*_edit_images.html.erb*

```
<% if @product.images != nil && @product.images.count > 0 %>
   <ul id="images_index" data-update-url="<%= sort_images_url %>">
   <% @product.images.order( :position ).each do |i| %>
      <%= content_tag_for :li, i do %>
         <%= image_tag i.image.url( :thumb ), class: "img-polaroid"  %>
         <%= link_to image_tag('icons/remove.png'), remove_image_from_product_products_path( product_id: @product.id, image_id: i.id ), remote: true, method: :get, data: { confirm: "Sure?"}, class: 'delete_item' %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
   </ul>
<% end %>
<a class="btn btn-default" id='add_image' href="#add_image_form"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
<%= form_tag '/admin/images', remote: true, multipart: true,  id: 'add_image_form' do %>
   <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<%= @product.id %>" />
   <br><%= label_tag 'name', 'Image title' %>
   <%= text_field_tag 'title', '', id: "add_image_title", class:'form-control' %><br>
   <%= label_tag 'name', 'Выберите файл' %>
   <%= file_field_tag 'file', class:'form-control'%><br><br>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add image</button>
<% end %>
```

The form calls the Images controller create action

```
  def create
     image = Image.create( title: params[ :title ], image: params[ :file ] )
     @product = Product.find_by id: params[ :product_id ]
     @product.images << image
     respond_to do |format|  
        format.html { redirect_to admin_products_path }  
        format.js   { render '/products/edit_images' }  
     end  
  end
```

After an Image was added and displied javascript doesn't work. Can anyone suggest a way to reload javascript after rendering partial?

**UPDATE**
images.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $("a#add_image").on "click", (e) ->
    $("form#add_image_form").toggle()
    e.preventDefault()

  $('div.actions ul#images_index').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
```

Comment: What does your JS look like?  Are you using `on()` to attach your event handler?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. Setting event listeners on page update solves the problem

```
images_update = ->
  $("#add_page_image").on "click", (e) ->
    $("form#add_image_form").toggle()
    e.preventDefault()

  $('#page_images_index').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))

$(document).on 'page:update', ->
  images_update()
```